# Date Picker in Ui5 allows to enter integers

Tags: sapui5

I have a date picker in my XML view and it allowed to enter integer and even saved. How to validate if the user entered in right date format.

```
<DatePicker value="{model>Date}" valueFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            displayFormat="dd/MMM/YYYY" change="Change"/>
```

Comment: Do you want validation after input ends or when the user pressed some kind of Save button?

Comment: @MatthijsMennens anything is fine. I think but just after user focusses out from date picker would be best to tell him. I was thinking of doing something by calling a change function. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, THI.

Hope it helps.

```
    onChange: function(oEvent) {
        var bValid = oEvent.getParameter("valid");
        var oDP = oEvent.getSource();

        if (!bValid) {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Entered date range isn't valid");
            oDP.setValueState("Error");
            return;
        }
    },
```